# Is it possible to have an optional type in Generics?

Tags: c#

I've seen a few almost similiar questions, but not exactly what I'm going for here.

Assume:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
}
```

I also have:

```
class MyClass<T> : MyBaseClass
{
    void SomeFunc(T t1, T t2)
    {
    } 
}
```

Normally t1 and t2 should be the same type. However, I ran into an edge case where they are not, so I need a:

```
class MyClass<T1, T2> : MyBaseClass
{
}
```

Is it possible to just have the T1 / T2 version and somehow mark T2 as = to T1 by default unless its specified?

Right now I have 2 separate classes... just wondering if there is any syntatic sugar to combine them into one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can derive one-argument `MyClass<T>` from two-argument class:

```
class MyBaseClass {
}

class MyClass<T1,T2> : MyBaseClass {
    void SomeFunc(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
    } 
}

class MyClass<T> : MyClass<T,T> {
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I still have 2 classes. I guess there isn't a way to do something like MyClass<T1, T2=T1> :)... obviously that's not legal, but that's what I was going for...